# Creating a javascript hash table that preserves order?

Tags: javascript

I looked around but nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to figure out if you can have a hash table that also preserves order but at the same time gives you the benefit of accessing the values by the key names (instead of by an index number).

Say that I have a hash table:

```
var productsSelected = {
  cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz",
  memory: "8GB",
  videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS",
  display: "27-inch LCD",
  extraBattery: "",
  antivirus: "",
  mouse: "Logitech 232",
  extendedWarranty: ""
}
```

I want to loop through this object using Handlebars and display the list of products selected in an order confirmation page.

The products that are displayed in the order confirmation list need to be in a certain order. I don't want the antivirus to be displayed at the top of the list, followed by the CPU, for example. I want it to be CPU-memory-videoCard- etc...

I've considered adding numbers to the key names:

```
var productsSelected = {
  a100-cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz",
  a110-memory: "8GB",
  a120-videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS",
  .
  .
```

But this is an awfully stupid way to do it.

There's also

```
var productsSelectedArray = [
  {cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz"},
  {memory: "8GB"},
  {videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS"},
  {display: "27-inch LCD"},
  {extraBattery: ""},
  {antivirus: ""},
  {mouse: "Logitech 232"},
  {extendedWarranty: ""}
]
```

But that's goofy to loop through - maybe? How would I loop through it but only display the key name, for example?

So ideally a hash table that preserves order, works in all browsers (I gather that different browsers treat hash table order differently), and where the values can be accessed via their keys (and maybe also by their index), like

`productsSelected.memory` returns "8GB"

`productsSelected[1].value` also returns "8GB"

`productsSelected[1].key` might return "memory"

Or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map that perserves order is also known as linked hashmap.
Here's a link that shows how to construct one in javascript:

http://dailyjs.com/2012/09/24/linkedhashmap/

If you're looking for a solution built in javascript, I don't think that it exists. Each browser has its own implementation on traversing objects.

Comment: Awesome - I think this script has promise!

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't just specify the keys in an array, and then just use the array to access the properties in order?

```
var keys = ['cpu', 'memory', 'videoCard'];

for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(productsSelected[keys[i]]);
};
```

You can even have the keys as a property of the object if you need to.

```
for (var i = 0, l = productsSelected.keys.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(productsSelected[productsSelected.keys[i]]);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gb9R4/1/)

Comment: Very cool and clever way to do this. I would ideally prefer not to have to explicitly define a separate keys array though.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, explicitly defining the keys is a great way to explicitly define the order as well.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it more - couldn't this work as well using Underscore?

All the hashes are in a certain order:

```
productsSelectedArray = [
  {cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz"},
  {memory: "8GB"},
  {videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS"},
  {display: "27-inch LCD"},
  {extraBattery: ""},
  {antivirus: ""},
  {mouse: "Logitech 232"},
  {extendedWarranty: ""}
];
```

For displaying all the keys in order we can use Underscore:

```
for (var i = 0, l = productsSelectedArray.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log( _.keys(productsSelectedArray[i]) );
};
```

And then for displaying all the values in order we can use Underscore as well.

```
for (var i = 0, l = productsSelectedArray.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log( _.values(productsSelectedArray[i]) );
};
```